# Comboxbox changing the linked cell of another Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

My code example for this is:

```
Private Sub ComboBox19_Change()

   iRow_Data = ComboBox19.ListIndex + 3

   If Sheet1.Range("C21") <> Sheet5.Cells(iRow_Data, 1) Then
       Sheet1.Range("C21") = Sheet5.Cells(iRow_Data, 1)
   End If

End Sub
```

The issue I am running into is when I select a value from the combobox in column 2 it is supposed to change the value of the linked cell of a different combobox in column 3, which it does do, but the combobox (column 3) with the altered linked cell does not display that value.

[image: An example of this problem].

If I move the combobox (column 3) in question you can see that the linked cell was in fact changed, but does not display the value in the combobox.

[image: Linked Cell changed]

Is there a way to get the linked cell value that has been altered by another combobox (column 2) to display in the other combobox (column 3).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this is your problem.

You're currently putting the value in the **Cell C21**. You want to instead put it in the combobox that *occupies* Cells C21. So replace `Sheet1.Range("C21")` with `MyComboBox.Value`, replacing "MyComboBox" with the name of the combobox in Cell C21. For best results, precede the combobox with its worksheet parent (i.e., `Worksheets(1).MyComboBox.Value`).

Comment: Holy moly you are a legend! Thank you!

Comment: Now that the comboboxes are linked using the method you suggested my clear macro doesn't empty the comboboxes properly. When one combobox is cleared the other is altered. This is creating unnecessary looping, but also makes it look messy. Can you think of any work arounds? I'm at a loss

Comment: To solve this I simply emptied the cells directly preceding the list indexes for the comboboxes. I imagine there is a better way to do this, but it worked. I think there was an issue with the Listindex being set to -1 when the linked cell or combobox selection was removed which then filled the value from the cell I was using as the header for the listfillrange.